# How to pass KeyCode via TextBox.OnKeyUp property in MS-Access VBA

Tags: ms-access, events, vba, parameter-passing

In MS Access, I use VBA to set an event handler function for multiple TextBoxes:

```
txtMyTextBox.OnKeyUp = "=myEventHandlerFunction()"
```

So far, this works fine. However I want to pass the KeyCode of the key that has been pressed. When I create "usual" KeyUp events manually for a TextBox, it automatically provides *KeyCode As Integer* and *Shift As Integer*. I was expecting that these could be used with the OnKeyUp property as well, like this:

```
txtMyTextBox.OnKeyUp = "=myEventHandlerFunction(KeyCode)"
```

Of course I updated myEventHandlerFunction so that it expects this argument. However, when the event is triggered, Access gives me an error, saying that the expression caused an error because the object doesn't contain the automation object *KeyCode*.

Is there any possibility how I can provide myEventHandlerFunction with the KeyCode using the OnKeyUp property? Am I using the wrong format or even the wrong parameter name (I'm using Access in German language, if that matters)?

The [MSDN documentation on the TextBox.OnKeyUp Property (Access)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/access-vba/articles/textbox-onkeyup-property-access) doesn't provide any information about this.

I know I could manually set up the KeyUp event for every TextBox and call myEventHandlerFunction from there with the KeyCode argument. This is not what I want since I want to set the event handling programatically, and to my understanding this requires using the OnKeyUp property.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the way you're handling events. You shouldn't set program handlers as text expressions, but instead use classes and OOP to set event handlers for your text boxes.

Example:

Use the following classes:

**clsTextboxHandler**

```
Public textboxesHandler As clsTextboxesHandler
Public WithEvents txt As Access.Textbox

Private Sub txt_KeyUp(KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    textboxesHandler.HandleKeyUp txt, KeyCode, Shift
End Sub
```

**clsTextboxesHandler**

```
Private TextboxHandlers As Collection

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set TextboxHandlers = New Collection
End Sub

Public Sub LoadAllTextboxes(ByRef TheForm As Access.Form)
    Dim ctl As Control
    For Each ctl In TheForm.Controls
        If ctl.ControlType = acTextbox Then 'Add additional criteria to only handle certain textboxes
            LoadTextbox ctl                
        End If
    Next ctl
End Sub

Public Sub LoadTextbox(txt As Access.Textbox)
    Dim TextboxHandler As New clsTextboxHandler
    Set TextboxHandler.txt= txt
    Set TextboxHandler.textboxesHandler = Me
    txt.OnKeyUp = "[Event Procedure]"
    TextboxHandlers.Add TextboxHandler
End Sub

Public Sub HandleKeyUp(txt As Access.Textbox, KeyCode As Integer, Shift As Integer)
    'Handle your KeyUp for multiple textboxes here. You can use the textbox object, keycode, etc.
End Sub
```

And on the form:

```
Private TextboxesHandler As clsTextboxesHandler
Public Sub Form_Load()
    Set TextboxesHandler = New clsTextboxesHandler
    TextboxesHandler.LoadAllTextboxes Me
End Sub
```

This has numerous advantages, such as being able to use additional handlers in the form module for certain controls, and being able to refer to the control calling the event in your handler.

Comment: @Jorg the edit is okay, I personally use different code to load single textboxes from a form, and to load multiple textboxes from a form (I often iterate through textboxes on the form, and call `LoadTextbox` from the form).

Comment: Yes, I think both can be done with the edit as well. Thank you for this elaborated approach, it appears the most professional to me.