# How to reduce repeated VBA code

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have an identical AfterUpdate event for 11 fields in my form. Is there any way to put the AfterUpdate code in a function or module and then call the function or module in each AfterUpdate event?

If a certain field is changed on the main form, I prompt the user with a message box saying they need to add a note in the subform describing the change. If the user clicks OK on the message box, it brings the focus to the note subform. If the user clicks Cancel, the change is undone in the main form.

Below is the code that is repeated for 11 fields:

```
Private Sub ID_AfterUpdate()

On Error GoTo StandardErrorHandling

Dim NoteReq As Integer

NoteReq = MsgBox("A change has been made to a protected field! " & _
"Please provide a note with a brief description of the change." _
, vbOKCancel, "A Note is Required!")

If Form.Dirty = True Then

    If NoteReq = vbCancel Then

        Me.Undo

    ElseIf NoteReq = vbOK Then

    'You may have to set focus to the subform then the control

    [Forms]![MainForm].[SubFormNotes].SetFocus

    DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec 'Go to new note record, not existing one

    End If

End If

ExitStandardErrorHandling:
Exit Sub

StandardErrorHandling:

MsgBox "The following error has occured:" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "Error Number: " & Err.Number & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
            "Error Description: " & Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
             , vbCritical, "An Error has Occurred!"

Resume ExitStandardErrorHandling

End Sub
```

I know a function returns a value so if I put the above code in a function, and called the function within the AfterUpdate event of each field, how would I code it so that it returns a value? Or is there another way to cut down on the redundant code? Thanks!

Comment: Your question is too broad in my opinion. There are several ways to go about it. You can take inspiration from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49790085/7296893) (or look at the approach attempted in the question, though I don't prefer that approach).

Comment: How are you going to stop this from being an infinite loop. You don't seem to have any check to see if the note has been added already? What kind of return value do you want from your function? You just define your function "AS <insert vartype>" and then setting the value to your function name will set your return value.

Comment: How do I check if the note has been added already? It's a one to many relationship so I didn't think it would be possible to check if there was a note added since an undefined number of notes can be added at a time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions don't seem to need to return a value in my experience. I've made functions to do exactly this sort of thing - highlight a textbox by changing the BackColor when selected, make several buttons do a set process to another control that shares a tag, swap values between Active and Previous controls etc.

You should be able to create a function directly from that coding simply by replacing the first line with something along the lines of `Function UpdateNote()` and the last line with `End Function`, and then do a find and replace "`sub`" with "`function`"

Then you can call that function simply by putting exactly `=UpdateNote()` (or whatever you call the funtion) in the After Update event property (directly in the property list, not vba or macro).

You can even apply it to all the different field's properties at once, by selecting all 11 of them and pasting that `=UpdateNote()` in the After Update event property.

It definitely *works*, and is pretty neat and clean in my opinion. If there's a reason it's not ideal, I'm not aware of it...

Comment: While that works, it's an old technique, and usually, the preferred technique is the one I shared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49790085/7296893). The main advantages of this newer technique are: you can use the built-in parameters, like `Cancel` and `KeyCode` (and if you pass them `ByRef`, you can even change them), you can refer to the control calling the function, and you can assign additional functions to specific controls using the form module. The main disadvantages are the length & complexity of the required code, and the number of modules.

Comment: Should I put the function in the class object for the form or create a module? Thanks!

Comment: If its something that you're only going to use for that form, personally I'd put it in the class object for the form, but I'm unsure what's considered best practice. If you're likely to use lots of functions in this way (which Erik tells us isn't best practice, or at least not his favourite) it might be worth creating a "QuickFunctions" module to keep them all together.
Personally I like this method as it seems simple, straightforward and easy. Perhaps it doesn't scale as well for large projects.