# How to determine the Object Type from the field name in a form?

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I am trying to generalize this Sub. The sub works, without the test for the checkbox, for text fields. A checkbox has no `.BackStyle` nor a `.ForeColor` property.

I tried the code below:

```vb
Private Sub EnableEdit(strFieldname As String, Optional bUseRed As Boolean = False)
    Me.Controls(strFieldname).Enabled = True
    Me.Controls(strFieldname).Locked = False
    If Not(TypeOf (Me.Controls(strFieldname)) Is CheckBox) Then
        Me.Controls(strFieldname).BackStyle = 1
        If bUseRed Then
            Me.Controls(strFieldname).ForeColor = vbRed
        Else
            Me.Controls(strFieldname).ForeColor = vbBlack
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

However

```
If Not(TypeOf (Me.Controls(strFieldname)) Is CheckBox) Then
```

is not syntactically correct. `TypeOf` expects an object and `Me.Controls(strFieldname)` is the control itself.

I tried alternative ways for `Me.Controls(strFieldname)`.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/early-late-binding/determining-object-type

Comment: Side note: the docs you linked to are VB.Net, not VBA.

Comment: It's `msforms.checkbox`  `typename` will give `checkbox`

Comment: Syntactically, you have too many parenthesis.  Try `If Not TypeOf Me.Controls(strFieldname) Is CheckBox Then`.

Comment: In case you're wondering about @BrianMStafford 's point: Enclosing an object in parentheses like you did will evaluate its default property. E.g. `(Range("A1"))` is the same as `Range("A1").Value` etc. You can also use `If TypeName(Me.Controls(strFieldname)) <> "CheckBox" Then`

Comment: Thank you for those answers as well: I learnt a lot of details today!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using standard Access controls, the easiest way is just to access the `ControlType` property

```
If Not Me.Controls(strFieldname).ControlType = acCheckbox Then
```

For special controls, TypeOf can be beneficial. You need to specify the class, which is likely `Access.Checkbox` (`msforms.Checkbox` can be used in Access as well but is very unusual).

```
If Not TypeOf Me.Controls(strFieldname) Is Access.Checkbox Then
```

The main source of your error, by the way, is the excessive use of parentheses. If you surround an object with parentheses, you get its default property:

```
Me.Controls("MyCheckbox") 'A checkbox

(Me.Controls("MyCheckbox")) 'The value of a checkbox
```

Comment: Works with this fix like a charm. However when I went through my code to apply the patch I realized it becomes very tedious, as the code has to be placed in the modules of each form. Is there possibly a way to rewrite it so that it can be placed in an own module and just be called from the forms? This is not possible now due to the 'Me.'.

Comment: Of course. Without more details it's hard to know exactly what you want, but you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49790085/7296893) as a starting point.

Comment: Hmm, I don't see right now how your link can help me. I reworked my code and I think I found a partial solution, but I'm not sure if it is optimal. As this is a different problem I  open a new question for it. Maybe you can give any input to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65249587/looking-for-a-better-way-to-set-properties-for-form-controls).

Answer (score 0):

The line `If Not(TypeOf (Me.Controls(strFieldname)) Is CheckBox) Then` has a problem:

1. The correct syntax would be:

```
If Not TypeOf Me.Controls(strFieldname) Is CheckBox Then
```

Comment: This is Access, not Excel.

Comment: That's what I mean. The question is about Access 2010.

Comment: @Gustav: Deleted the Excel specific part. The above syntax should work in Access, too.