# Access - MouseDown Event not triggered

Tags: vba, ms-access

First and foremost I would like to say that I am new to Access and please excuse me in advance if my question is silly. That said, I have created a very simple form in Access and want to display a message every time the mouse has been pressed. For that reason I added the following code attached to the "Mouse Down" event in Access:

```
Private Sub Form_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    MsgBox "Click"
End Sub
```

However, it doesn't work no matter how many times I click my mouse. I have tried to move it to "Mouse Up" and "Mouse Move", but it seems that the mouse events cannot be triggered. That said, when I put the event to "Key Press" everything is working fine.

I would be really grateful if you can maybe guess what the cause of the problem is. Could it be that I am using a Razor mouse? It seems weird that the key press trigger was successful, but none of the mouse ones are working. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you clicking on the form itself? That's where you put the code. It will not trigger if you click on something like a textbox or a button that is on the form. That is a different event.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're likely looking for `Detail_MouseDown`

`Form_MouseDown` affects the record selector.

The entire form body is the details section, and that's affected by `Details_MouseDown`.

Note that, as stated earlier, records and labels have separate `MouseDown` events. If you want to capture all mouse clicks on a form, one approach is to have an object that handles these events (and possibly redirects them back to the form) and initialize this on `Form_Load` for each control. See  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49790085/7296893) for some guidance, but note you unfortunately need objects for each kind of control.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation. Once I moved it to "Detail" it started working with no issue.

Answer (score 1):

From: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/access.form.mousedown

*"To cause a MouseDown event for a form to occur, press the mouse button in a blank area or record selector on the form. To cause a MouseDown event for a form section to occur, press the mouse button in a blank area of the form section."*

So you need a "blank area" to click on.

Comment: Thank you for the reference article. It turned out that I was using the function in the wrong place.